# Can't I create a rest API in the apollo-server?

Tags: graphql, nexus, rest, apollo-server, prisma

It is currently being developed using mysql-prisma-apollo server-nexus, and it is necessary to receive row data post using the REST API, not the GrqphQL statement currently developed. You want to process raw data passed to the post in Path (for example,/api/data/status). Is there a way to create a RestAPI on the apollo-server?

Answer (score 0):

The apollo-server runs in a node environment, so you are able to use any http client you want.

Example:

- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
- [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)